# Point domain name at Windows Server 2008 static IP

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, domain, ip

basically I have a domain name and I want to add it to my Windows Server 2008 RC2 install. I have web services setup so I can view my webpages and whatnot when I go to the server's IP, but I want to have my domain point to the IP.

I also run it as a minecraft server so this is primarily why I want the domain name to point to my server as remembering the IP sucks!

Can someone point me in the direction of a guide or video?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a fixed IP (range), then you have to configure your DNS settings at your ISP. There you should be able to configure through their webpage the DNS settings for your domain, assigning a name to your IP address, an A record (check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types). Read DNS basics to understand them, setting things wrong could make you loose your mails and more.

If what you have is a dynamic IP then it's a bit more complicated, but there are several services offering you names that associate semi-automatically to your actual IP (as an example check http://www.dyndns.com/). These can be configured on most firewalls/routers today. I hope your server is not connected directly to the internet with only a modem ...